# BindingSource and tableAdapter changes not commiting to the database - C#, Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, database, commit, bindingsource

I've seen a lot of problems that are closely related to this but haven't found a solution, so I'm asking. I created a insert into query using the wizard and the tableAdapter that is automatically generated when you drag and drop the datasource into your Windows form. When I put all my data(is a sign up screen) and push sign up, the tableAdapter does the update with the following commands:

```
this.userTableAdapter.InsertQuery(loginText.Text.Trim(), nameText.Text.Trim(), int.Parse(ageText.Text), trackBar1.Value, trackBar2.Value, trackBar3.Value, passwordText.Text.Trim(), false, sex.Text.Trim());
            try
            {
                //this.Validate();
                //this.userBindingSource.EndEdit();
                this.userTableAdapter.Update(this.databaseJogoDataSet.user);
                MessageBox.Show("UPDATED!!!");
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Update Failed");
            }
```

The "UPDATED!!!" messagebox is shown and the login starts to work with the new data, but once I close the program these new datum is wiped from the database. How can I commit the changes I did and permanently write them to the DB?

Thanks.

Comment: should you be calling something like `AcceptChanges?`

Comment: Didn't work. Also, I did some research and found this, saying it doesn't commit: http://forums.asp.net/t/1340048.aspx?difference+between+dataset+acceptchanges+and+dataadapter+update+in+net