# Can't save the dataset changes to the database in C# - Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2013, dataset

[SOLVED]
SOLUTION: When you execute the program inside visual studio it won't commit the changes to the database, but instead, it will work with a copy. When you deploy your program to an executable file, this executable is able to modify permanently your database. Hope this helps anyone :)

As i've said in this question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051351/bindingsource-and-tableadapter-changes-not-commiting-to-the-database-c-visua), I can't save the changes of my dataset to my DataBase. I tried to follow this tutorial [HERE](https://yadavsachin.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/save-dataset-changes-to-database-in-c/comment-page-1/#comment-68) and couldn't get it to work either: The program compiles and executes, but the new data isn't committed to the DB. Here's the code I wrote following the turorial.

//METHOD INSIDE MY SIGN UP WINDOWS FORM

```
    public static SqlDataAdapter GetuserRecord()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\DatabaseJogo.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        string query = "Select * from dbo.[user]";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        MessageBox.Show("CONNECTION SUCCESFUL");
        return adp;
    }
```

//WHEN MY SIGN UP BUTTON IS CLICKED:

```
            SqlDataAdapter adp = GetuserRecord();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            adp.Fill(ds);

            DataRow newRow = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
            newRow["login"] = loginText.Text.Trim();
            newRow["name"] = nameText.Text.Trim();
            newRow["age"] = int.Parse(ageText.Text.Trim());
            newRow["graphicsScore"] = trackBar1.Value;
            newRow["storyScore"] = trackBar2.Value;
            newRow["gameplayScore"] = trackBar3.Value;
            newRow["password"] = passwordText.Text.Trim();
            newRow["isAdmin"] = isAdmin.Checked;
            newRow["sex"] = sex.Text.Trim();

            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newRow);

            SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adp);

            adp.UpdateCommand = commandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand(true);
            adp.InsertCommand = commandBuilder.GetInsertCommand(true);
            adp.DeleteCommand = commandBuilder.GetDeleteCommand(true);

            adp.Update(ds);
```

EDIT: CHANGED THE CODE TO A NEW ONE, BUT THE PROBLEM IS STILL THE SAME. IF YOU WANT TO TAKE A LOOK, HERE IT IS:

```
                //TRY 3 SQL
            //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.commit(v=vs.110).aspx
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\DatabaseJogo.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            SqlTransaction transaction;

            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SIGNUP");

            command.Connection = connection;
            command.Transaction = transaction;
            try
            {
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [user] ([login], [name], [age], [graphicsScore], [storyScore], [gameplayScore], [password], [isAdmin], [sex]) VALUES (@login, @name, @age, @graphicsScore, @storyScore, @gameplayScore, @password, @isAdmin, @sex);";
                command.Parameters.Add("@login", SqlDbType.NChar, 50).Value = loginText.Text.Trim();
                command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NChar, 50).Value = nameText.Text.Trim();
                command.Parameters.Add("@age", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(ageText.Text.Trim());
                command.Parameters.Add("@graphicsScore", SqlDbType.Int).Value = trackBar1.Value;
                command.Parameters.Add("@storyScore", SqlDbType.Int).Value = trackBar2.Value;
                command.Parameters.Add("@gameplayScore", SqlDbType.Int).Value = trackBar3.Value;
                command.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.NChar, 50).Value = passwordText.Text.Trim();
                command.Parameters.Add("@isAdmin", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = isAdmin.Checked;
                command.Parameters.Add("@sex", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = sex.Text.Trim();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                transaction.Commit();
                MessageBox.Show("COMMITTED");
            }
            catch (Exception expt)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(expt.Message);
                try
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
                catch (Exception ex2)
                {
                    // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred 
                    // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as 
                    // a closed connection.
                    MessageBox.Show("Rollback Exception Type: " + ex2.GetType());
                    MessageBox.Show("  Message: " + ex2.Message);
                }
            }
            //connection.UpdateDatabase(ds);

            connection.Close();
```

Comment: Are you giving the correct Column name as similar to the Database Table column name `newRow["login"]` - `login`- is this similar to table column name?. The Column Names may be case Sensitive so, try to give exact column name

Comment: Yes, I am prasy. I can login to my account and see all the details I entered in the sign up screen after I sign up with the form with this code. The only problem is as soon as I close the program the new users are deleted from the DB.

Comment: Can you wrap in a try/catch block to see if you're getting an exception on that Update?

Comment: @ragerory Tried with try
                {
                    adp.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
                }
                catch(Exception expt)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(expt.Message);
                } and no exceptions were thrown!

Answer (score 0):

In order to Updateupdate the data on the database your SqlDataAdapter need to have its InsertCommand, UpdateCommand, DeleteCommand properties set.

So, try the below code:

```
 ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newRow);
 SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adp);
 adp.DeleteCommand = commandBuilder.GetDeleteCommand(true);
 adp.UpdateCommand = commandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand(true);
 adp.InsertCommand = commandBuilder.GetInsertCommand(true);
 adp.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
 //connection.UpdateDatabase(ds);
 connection.Close();
```

Edit:
The Update method takes the name of a DataSet and a table. The DataSet for us is ds, which is the one we passed in to our UpdateDatabase method when we set it up. After a dot, you type the name of a table in your dataset.

Comment: Didn't fix the whole problem. The first way I did it(with the built-in table adapter) worked the same way this routine is working: the data is saved to the DataSet and I can access the new data I inserted into the dataset, but when I close the program the new Data is cleaned up. Thanks!

Comment: @RodrigoGuimarães :see my edits...you have to pass the dataset table in Update Method and One thing i noticed is always close the connection after you have performed insert/delete/update operation.

Comment: I tried, closed the connection, and changed to  adp.Update(ds.Tables[0]);, but the problem is still the same. Thanks again.

Comment: The command connection.UpdateDatabase(ds); is not available and I found nothing about it on Google. What namespace does it belong to?

Comment: @RodrigoGuimarães : Sorry that was copy and paste error my code. Ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

I am going thru the same thing:
I can create the dataset, then insert, update and delete, then have the changed dataset's data displayed. This works so far as expected as all the changes of the dataset show. But you can run this again and again, so: the data in the underlying database is not changed.

Either some final commit somewhere is missing or it just does not work as it should and as these methods are not current any more nobody cares.
Sincerly
Andi